Using setCurrentItem(index, false) with Viewpager2 not working
I am using Viewpager2 and calling setCurrentItem(index, false) but Viewpager2 still smooth scroll. I am using with this library SegmentedProgressBar.
When commenting out the code for the library, viewpager doesn't smooth scroll.
Here are the codes
private fun initViewPager() {
        mBinding.viewpager.apply {
            isUserInputEnabled = false
            adapter = mAdapter
            setCurrentItem(1, false)

            registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                    if (state == ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (currentItem == mAdapter.itemCount - 1) {
                            AppUtils.setTimeout({

                                setCurrentItem(1, false)
                            }, 1000)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    if (mIsInitialized && position != mAdapter.itemCount - 1) {
                        mAdapter.play(position)
                    }
                }
            })

            setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mIsOnHold) {
                    mBinding.segmentProgress.start()
                    mAdapter.resume(currentItem)
                    mIsOnHold = false
                }

                return@setOnTouchListener if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    true
                } else {
                    super.onTouchEvent(event)
                }
            }

            post {
                mViewPagerWidth = width
            }
        }

        initSegmentProgress()
    }

    private fun initSegmentProgress() {
        mBinding.segmentProgress.apply {
            segmentCount = 4
            timePerSegmentMs = 5000L
            listener = object : SegmentedProgressBarListener {
                override fun onPage(oldPageIndex: Int, newPageIndex: Int) {
                    if (!mIsInitialized || oldPageIndex == -1) return

                    mBinding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(newPageIndex + 1, false)
                }

                override fun onFinished() {
                    mBinding.viewpager.currentItem += 1
                    restartSegment()
                }
            }

            setPosition(0)
            start()
            mIsInitialized = true
        }
    }

    private fun initGestureDetector() {
        mGestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                if (e.x < mViewPagerWidth / 2) {
                    if (mBinding.viewpager.currentItem == 1) {
                        mBinding.segmentProgress.restartCurrentSegment()
                        mAdapter.restart()
                    } else {
                        mBinding.segmentProgress.previous()
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mBinding.viewpager.currentItem < mAdapter.itemCount - 1) {
                        mBinding.segmentProgress.next()
                    } else {
                        mBinding.segmentProgress.restartSegment()
                    }
                }

                return true
            }

            override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                mIsOnHold = true
                mBinding.segmentProgress.pause()
                mAdapter.pause(mBinding.viewpager.currentItem)
            }

            override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })
    }

This is for infinite viewpager. The logic is working but the issue is with smooth scroll. I want to set current item without smooth scroll but it didn't work.
